# How to cite "revised" edition in bibtex?

Tags: bibtex

How can I cite a book with a "Revised edition" instead of the common Xth edition format?

Comment: Please tell us which bibliography style you employ.

Comment: Better yet, give us an MWE …

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion:

```
edition = {Revised},
```

This approach is known to "work" with a lot of bibliography styles, not just the `plainnat` style employed below. For instance, it also works with the `apacite` citation management package and the `apacite` bibliography style.

---

A full MWE (minimum working example) that uses the `natbib` citation management package and the `plainnat` bib style:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{mybib.bib}
@book{aa:99,
  author  = {Anne Author},
  title   = {Thoughts},
  publisher = {Great Press},
  address = {Anytown},
  year    = 1999,
  edition = {Revised},
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat} % select a suitable bib style

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

An informal way to do this would be to add the following field to the Bibtex entry:

```
note = {Revised edition},
```

Another informal way would be to attach it to the title

```
title = {My Book, Revised edition},
```